# How do I create a html page that hasbutton(not of <form>) where each one of them redirects to another page made with html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, express

i made a html login page with node server on giving correct password i life to send user to another page like(localhost:8081/    to   localhost:8081/user)

but i am using ajax request for this.Here server is sending html page as variable (in node i am using `res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "finalbox.html");`) 
.So i am unable to redirect to new page

please write a code sample **using express module** like `var express = require('express');`, `var app = express();` and using ajax request (if possible) to display new webpage .(**dont use form in html**)

Comment: is using `window.location` redirection not acceptable?

Comment: Hyperlink? What is the point of using node to generate a html page and send it back with ajax if a normal link would suffice? Also, 'please write code sample using ....' is probably not a good question here. The point is that You write the code sample and we help you remove the bugs from it. No code, no decent answers.

Comment: thank you for your response .I was trying to match user name and password with values in m database and if they match ,i send home page to user . Can you suggest me best way to do this (i will be grateful if you suggest me with link)